# Issues while using Jetty Embedded to handle JSP. (JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, embedded-jetty

I am trying to set up Jetty Embedded to handle JSPs.

The HelloServlet works properly when I type *localhost:8080*. I get the list of the files in the jsp folder when I type *localhost:8080/jsp*, but if I take an index.jsp into the folder I will get an exception. The JSP contains only a short HTML text and this line in the body: `<%= new java.util.Date() %>`.

What could be the problem?

This is the exception:

```
2013-07-08 16:29:10.007:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1957204991-11: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:661)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: 
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.getClassLoader(ContextHandler.java:2161)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagPluginManager.init(TagPluginManager.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagPluginManager.apply(TagPluginManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my app:

```
package main;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class SimplestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/jsp");
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("./jsp/");
        webAppContext.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");   

        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()), "/*");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { webAppContext, servletContextHandler });

        server.setHandler(handlers);    
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

JSP code:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">;
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= new java.util.Date() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

I solved the previous problem [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892325/getclassloader-from-servletcontext-leads-to-accesscontrolexception). Now I am in trouble again.
I didn't changed anything, just added a new row to the policy file and I get a new exception, when I try to load the jsp page. ( `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext` )
I found a few articles about this, and it may happens because I added a tomcat library manually to my project. ( *tomcat-juli.jar* ). However if I delete this library from the project, I get an other exception (just after running the application, not when I want to load a JSP.) ( `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory` ). So that's because I added tomcat-juli.jar.

This is the full trace of the IllegalStateException exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:546)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(InstanceManagerFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:546)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I've added tomcat-juli.jar to the "Apache Tomcat v7.0" libraries. So this time I don't bundle the jar into my app, but I still get the IllegalStateException exception. In addition I don't understand why the app want to use tomcat libraries while I am using Jetty.

Comment: Show us your JSP . Are all the imports in place ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot note that OP uses full class name, so there's no need of imports.

Comment: The real problem looks to be how you execute your app, not with your jsp. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7892325/1065197

Comment: Yes, I used the full name.
The file only contains this:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @szedjani I've edited your question to reflect your JSP content. Note that this kind of code should be added in your question and not in comments.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks a lot. Do you know where can I find the start script if I am using Jetty Embedded?

Comment: That depends how you execute your app. If in Eclipse, then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7574543/1065197. If NetBeans, review: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html. If other, search it on the net. If directly from command line, then it's even simpler.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Note the comment was made before OP edited the question to include the JSP code :)

Comment: @TheNewIdiot note that the JSP code is irrelevant to the problem. Just check the stacktrace: *Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")*

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Note Luiggi Mendoza edited the question, not me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issues. I don't know what was the real solution for the original problem, but this way it works.

So I changed the target runtime of a new project to *J2EE Preview* instead of *Apache Tomcat v7.0*. (In Eclipse: *File -> New -> Dynamic Web Project -> New Runtime -> Basic -> J2EE Preview* ). Then I copied all of the file into this project.

I had a small issue after this. The program haven't find the *jasper.jar* then the *tools.jar*, so I added them manually to the project. (tools.jar located in the *lib* folder of the JDK and *jasper.jar* the part of the Apache Tomcat v7.0 library.) And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using below configuration in jetty-web.xml.

```
<Get name="ServletContext">
  <Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer">
            <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer"></New>
            </Arg>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager"></New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Get>
```

Jetty Version : 9.3.8

For embedded jetty please refer :
https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java